# is it possible to replace the host element with templating?

Tags: polymer

This is maybe a silly question as it seems quite obvious that it would be hard to implement but nevertheless i'd like to ask...

Taken this markup:

```
<input is="my-input" name="foo">
```

and this assumed component:

```
<polymer-element name="my-input">
    <template>
        <div>
            <span class="myinput" name="{{name}}">
        </div>
    </template>
  ....
```

Is it possible to turn in rendered DOM into:

```
<div>
     <span class="myinput" name="foo">
</div>
```

by effectively replacing the initial native HTML input?

The use case is to provide a fallback. If the browser is not capable of web components it will fall back to the native control. Furthermore authors can write the syntax they know: HTML - and can enhance the native control with a single 'is' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: No.

Shadow DOM encapsulation (as opposed to altering the user's DOM) is an essential concept in Polymer. There used to be a [`lightdom` attribute](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/polymer-dev/SyRhkUTuHDU/discussion) that would do something similar to what you're asking for, but it ended up being [removed](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/commit/abac5f034ca0fab2316bb66ad9d582033aa4be39) ([discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/polymer-dev/G50Kf349Af8/ApReQw_rOB0J)).

You could very easily [use native custom elements alone](http://jsbin.com/xugoqofi/1/edit?html,css,js,output) to implement something like this. Or maybe Mozilla's [x-tag](http://www.x-tags.org/) or IBM's [delite](http://ibm-js.github.io/delite/index.html) have this use case covered.

**Original Answer**

Use the [`extends` attribute](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#extending-other-elements) on your `polymer-element` tag:

```
<polymer-element name="my-input" extends="input" attributes="name">
```

Here's a [working example](https://ele.io/cletusw/my-input).

Comment: No, this doesn't answer the question. Look close - i wanted to know if it's possible that the element wearing the 'is' attribute is *replaced* by the template.